# JavaScript Date Format Normalizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, jquery-validate

I'm creating an HTML 5 form for mobile.  I'm using jquery-validate to validate my form.  My problem is in relation to date pickers across different phones.  They aren't consistent in the date format they store.  How can I detect the format they're storing?  Once I can detect it, I can then normalize it to some format before I post to the backend.

For example, iPhone does yyyy-mm-dd while Samsung S3 does mm/dd/yyyy.  The problem gets real fun when you think that some will have mm/dd/yyyy and others dd/mm/yyyy making 05/12/2012 either May 12th or Dec 5th 2012.  This will probably entail locale detection.  Hopefully there's a library out there that handles this for me already.

Comment: You can give a try to http://momentjs.com/ ?

Comment: @IrvinDominin - It won't really help. `05/12/2012` can actually mean both things.

Comment: +1 for momentjs. Saved me couple of times.